# XCode: reading data from plist into NSmutablearray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, plist

Here is my problem. I have a plist called myPlist and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">    
<plist version="1.0">    
<dict>    
<key>1</key>    
<array>    
<string>Dog</string>    
<string> empty </string>    
<true/>    
</array>    
<key>2</key>    
<array>    
<string>Car</string>    
<string> empty </string>    
<false/>    
</array>    
<key>3</key>    
<array>    
<string>Table</string>    
<string> empty </string>    
<true/>    
</array>
</dict>
```

It has three values for each key. Two are strings and one is Boolean. I tried the 'usual ways' to fill an nsmutablearray with the plist so I could show it in a tableview but the NSMutableArray is always empty. I tried this first:

```
NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:
             [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"]] retain];
```

Then I also tried this but it still returns 0 objects.

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];

        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSArray *mutable = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Root"]];
```

I always used dictionary-like plist and this is my first one with this kind of structure so I think I'm doing something wrong. Btw did I mention that I'm a noob? :)

Please help.

**EDIT**
Thanks to Rob, I can now read data using this line:

```
NSDictionary *dogObject = [dict objectForKey:@"1"];
```

But how can I transfer the data to a NSMutableArray so I could edit the data later? Or can I just save the edited data using dictionary?

Comment: are you getting correct path ? NSLog path object.

Comment: `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` should do it. Are you sure the path you are using is correct? Try printing it out with NSLog so you can check it. Or declare a separate NSString ivar for the path and set a breakpoint so you can view it directly in the code.

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. I checked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the end-tag for the top level `plist` tag.  I assume that is a copy/paste error.

If you add the missing `</plist>` at the end, that is a valid property list.  It contains a top-level dictionary, so you have to load it into an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`).

The top-level dictionary doesn't contain the key `Root`.  It contains three keys: `1`, `2`, and `3`.  So you could get an object from it like this:

```
NSDictionary *dogObject = [dict objectForKey:@"1"];
```

Comment: You were right with your code sample. I get now count = 3! How can I now load up everything in an array so I can see the count of that?

Comment: Iterate through the elements of the dictionary and add each one to an `NSMutableArray`.